# Modify subset of list inside click function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list of models which I am rendering using the following ng-click directive:

```
<div id="pair" ng-repeat="question in session.questions | filter:{'answered':qfilter}">
```

Inside each of these questions, I have a vote button which calls a vote method on click:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="vote(question, 1)" ng-class="{upvote: question.score == 1}">&#x25B2;</a><br/>
```

Notice that this ng-click directive is passing the question variable to my function.

Here's the vote function:

```
$scope.vote = function(question, val){
    $scope.apply(function(){
        if(question.vote == val){
            question.vote = 0;
        }else{
            question.vote = val;
        }
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: question.resource_uri+"vote/",
            data: $.param({vote:question.vote}),
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        });
    })
}
```

This function is being called fine, and the post is being submitted successfully. The only problem is that even after running a $scope.apply, the value of question.vote is still not being updated in the UI. I'm guessing that it has something to do with ng-repeat duplicating arrays, so modifying the new question is not in turn modifying the question in scope.

I have also tried updating the scope inline by returning the vote and using this ng-click:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="question.vote = vote(question, -1)" ng-class="{downvote: question.score == -1}">&#x25BC;</a>
```

Comment: It turns out that I accidentally used `question.score` instead of `question.vote` in `{upvote: question.score == 1}`. Now it works perfectly.